# Abstract class returning instances of a private nested class

Tags: java

I want an abstract class `A`.

Then I want a class `B` that can only be instantiated by `A`. No one else can access `B` - only `A`.

Then I want `A` to have a method that returns instances of `B`.

My attempt:

```
public abstract class A {

    public static B getInstanceOfB() {
        return new B();
    }

    private class B {

    }

}
```

Which of course doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you want by making class `B` as `private static`:

```
public abstract class A {
  ...

  private static class B {
    ...
  }

}
```

If the class `B` is not `static`, you should have an instance of `A` to access `B`. If you want to instantiate `B` without instantiating `A`, you should make the inner class `static`.

Perhaps there's reasons that you make `A` as `abstract` and `B` as private inner class. I think the intension is that you want to expose only interface and hide the concrete implementation type. Because abstract class is for subclassing, this can be achieved by making `B` as subtype of `A` and declare the common interface in `A`.

```
public abstract class A {
  ...
  private static class B extends A {
    ...
```

Now, you can create the instance of `B` outside the scope of `A`, as long as you specify the type of the object as `A`, like this:

```
A b = A.getInstanceOfB();
```

It would be better to remove the sign of specific type from the method name, and specify it by transferring argument.

```
A b = A.getInstance(...);
```

You can create the object of type what you need within the `getInstance()` factory method as specified argument.

Well, if `A` shouldn't be used like this, you can declare a public interface for the class `B` and use it as a type of `B` outside the scope of `A`.

```
public interface IB {...}
```

and

```
public abstract class A {
  ...
  private static class B implements IB {
    ...
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable that you're returning it into in the calling code?  It must be `Object` I suppose, for calling code outside of this class, but then the `B` isn't very useful.  You can't even cast it back into a `B`.  Sorry, but I'm really cynical of this.  I've tried this sort of thing before - no good ever came of it.

Comment: Make the actual class public and the constructor private. `A` will still be able to see the constructor.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, that works.  The solution as given - I'm not so sure.

Comment: This is wrong because B is not visible from outside. How are you going to use result object somewhere else outside A class?

Comment: @Mikhail has expressed this far more clearly than I managed to.  Upvoters, please explain?

Comment: @DavidWallace The first two upvoters probably agreed with the answer and then the rest were following the trend.

Comment: Change B to public and it solves my problems! I though that B should've been private to avoid instantiating it from outside, but now I see that it will still work if it is public since it is static.

Comment: @mikeyaworski It's OK.  I haven't downvoted this answer (but I thought about it), because there's the seed of something good inside it. I think it just needs some work.

Comment: @Omega the key is that class should be visible from outside, but impossible to instantiate. This could be achieved by making constructor private or by using interface. Both are correct.

Comment: @Omega Any class with a private constructor can't be instantiated except through a static factory method (or JVM trickery).

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, I missed some important things. I added some more explanation.

Comment: It seems like  you've changed your solution completely. Not sure about the wisdom of making `B` extend `A` - that might not fit what `B` is actually about.  `extends` is for "is a" relationships, but there's no indication in the question that there's any sort of "is a" relationship between the concepts that `A` and `B` represent.  I like the last little bit though - about having an interface that `B` implements.  It sounds a bit like something I would have written! :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Though this technique (making `B` extend `A`) is common in JDK source to hide implementation class, I'm not sure that this is what questioner wants. If there's no is-a relation, declaring an interface should be the answer, which is the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Have an interface (`BInterface` maybe) that lists the methods that the calling code is likely to use, on the instances of `B`.  Write `B implements BInterface`.  Then give `getInstanceOfB()` a return type of `BInterface`.  It can then be used from some other class, and that other class can then call the methods listed in `BInterface`, on whatever object is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You should make `B` public, but with package private constructor:

```
public abstract class A {
    public static B getInstanceOfB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

public class B {
    B(){}
}
```

Comment: that's not correct. You cannot instantiate B without object of A, unless B is static

Comment: @GV He's made it into a separate class entirely - it's not an inner class any more.  Your comment isn't right.

Comment: ohhk. Missed out on that, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Making the private class static removed the error which is produced in eclipse.

```
public abstract class A {

public static B getInstanceOfB() {
    return new B();
}



private static class B {

}

}
```